# How to solve this certificate problem with Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Since yesterday, I'm not able anymore to build my apps in Android Studio. After trying many "solutions" found on the Internet, I have found one asking to delete three folders : ".android", ".AndroidStudio3.6" and ".gradle". Now it's done, when I open Android Studio, it warns me that some certificate are expired (see the image below). The expiration date is in accordance with the date I first faced the problem so it really seems to be the problem.

Does anybody else face this problem? How could I solve it?

P.S : if I accept the expired certificates, when building, I get errors like Firebase 17.4.0 can be found.

As Hata made me notice, the certificates are not expired but only untrusted. I have then accepted them once again and, this time, Android Studio asked me to update the Firebase plugin. Despite this update, build is still unsuccessful. Here's my build result :

[image]

It seems to confirm my problem is related to a security certificate.

[image]

Another try : uninstalling Android Studio, deleting the three folders mentionned above (even for my admin account, where the ".gradle' folder was weighting more than 6Gb!) then reinstalling : same problem...

On another computer, my projects are correctly buiilt.

Comment: Why expired? Year 2021 is the next year. It says *not trusted*.

Comment: Yes, tou are right! The day and month fooled me. Question edited to take this into account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in fact related to my antivirus program. I uninstalled it and reinstalled it and the build is now successfull.